# probability of hand having cards from exactly two hands

Tags: statistics

Can you guys answer this question regarding part (c)? I am confused of what he means.

A deck of $52$ cards is mixed well, and $5$ cards are dealt.
(a) It can be shown that (disregarding the order in which the cards are dealt) there are $2,598,960$ possible hands, of which only $1287$ are hands consisting entirely of clubs.
(b) It can be shown that exactly $63,206$ hands contain only diamonds and spades, with both suits represented.
What is the probability that a hand consists entirely of diamonds and spades with both suits represented? (Give the answer to five decimal places.)
(c) Using the result of Part (b), what is the probability that a hand contains cards from exactly two suits? (Give the answer to five decimal places.)

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, there are also $63206$ hands with diamonds and hearts, with both suits represented.

There are also $63206$ hands with diamonds and clubs, with both suits represented.

The same applies to spades and hearts, to spades and clubs, and so on. Make a list. There are exactly $6$ types of hands that have exactly two suits, including the diamonds and spades case.

So there are $(6)(63206)$ hands that have exactly two suits. Thus for c) the answer of b) gets multiplied by $6$.